# Why is image mirrored in ImageButton Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an ImageButton with a left oriented arrow 
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDDeO.png)

```
<ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_left"
        android:layout_width="17sp"
        android:layout_height="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Why is the image mirrored/rotated and is shown as a
[right arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie1iU.png) in the application?

Comment: Assuming you're 100% sure the image you pasted above is `icon_arrow_left`, the problem should be on the orientation the image is reporting (Exif) and not related to Android.  I've never seen something like this ... but you might need to review the image with an Exif information explorer.

Comment: The image pasted above is 100% icon_arrow_left. The same image is used in multiple places in the application, but this is the only place it is shown this way. It is strange to me because I didn't do anything different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the image mirrored/rotated and is shown as a right arrow in the application

I didn't find the reason but I find that there are several solutions can solve this problem.

1. **Solution 1**

Use `android:background` attribute instead of `android:src` attribute :

```
<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/icon_arrow_left"
    ......
    />
```

2. **Solution 2**

Give your `ImageButton` a bigger size and a white background color, it will display normally, here is my code :

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_left"
    android:layout_width="51sp"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

2. **Solution 3**

Use `android:scaleType="center"` attribute, then give your `ImageButton` a bigger `layout_width` to adjust its position, code like this :

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_left"
    android:layout_width="30sp"
    android:layout_height="10sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    />
```

Their [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqqtD.png).

Comment: Solution 1 is the only one that works for me. I can't give my button a white background color (Solution 2) because there is a gradient background behind it. I fixed the problem by using the other arrow image, I.m not looking for a solution, but for an explanation.

Comment: @Madalin Sisu, once I find the reason, I will come back and update my answer.